# Redhat Enterprise Linux 4.7 - Ping problem

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ping

When I try to ping some of the IP addresses I get "connect: No buffer space is available" error. Also when I check /var/log/messages, there are some errors like as following

```
printk: 99 messages overflow
kernel: Neighbour table overflow
```

do you have any ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a related thread [here](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2004-10/8261.html) and a possible solution [here](http://www.gnulinuxclub.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=333&Itemid=49).

Basically this happens because the interface "neighbour" table fills up when too many different addresses connect to your server within a short interval. Increasing the table size and using more aggressive garbage collection for its contents resolves this issue.